# passing variable into index function - Python

Tags: python

Been working at this for quite a while, and I haven't found any examples on this site or any others that seem relevant. I have a list, and what I'm trying to do is pretty simple I think. I just need to search that list to find the key word "Buffer Log". Once I find that keyword, I need to print every line from that line, until the end of the list. Any direction at all would be very much appreciated. It seems like I'm pretty close.

```
logfile = open('logs.txt', 'r')
readlog = logfile.readlines()
logfile.close()

lines = []
for line in readlog:
    lines.append(line)


for x in lines:
    if "Log Buffer" in x:
       z =lines.index(x)
       print(lines[z:]
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop in which yoú're creating one more list called `lines`.

You can use `enumerate()` to keep track of which line number you are at, while searching for the line that contains `'Log Buffer'`

When you find the line that contains `'Log Buffer'`, just remember that line number, exit the loop, and then print all lines from readlog starting from that line number.

```
logfile = open('logs.txt', 'r')
readlog = logfile.readlines()
logfile.close()

for i,x in enumerate(readlog):
    if 'Log Buffer' in x:
        z = i # Remember the value of i for which the line had 'Log Buffer'
        break # Exit the loop.

print (*readlog[z:])  # Move your print statement outside the loop.
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the code:

```
lines = []
for line in readlog:
    lines.append(line)
```

Is unnecessary because readlog is already a list. You can try something along the lines of this:

```
found = False
for line in readlog: # because this is already a list
    if "Log Buffer" in line:
        found = True # set our logic to start printing
    if found:
        print(line)
```